# Why does Firefox suddenly disable Javascript by itself?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am using Firefox 28.0 on Mac OS 10.6.8. Sometimes during web development, probably after my application crashes, Firefox suddenly disables Javascript in one particular tab. So my application would be all weird and not work until I restart Firefox. The script panel would say that the page has no scripts, and if I open another page with Javascript in the same tab, it would not work either.

Is it some kind of safety feature? Is it documented anywhere? Note that I also have Firebug installed, and I managed to crash Firefox by profiling my app in Firebug on more than one occasion.

I checked `about.config`; `javascript.enabled` is set to `true`.

Comment: Same problem here. It started after I updated Firefox. I also installed the Selenium Addon. But i don't know what caused it. I also have plugins for enabling/disabling javascript but even after deactivating them the problem still exists... Did you find a solution yet?